# Is Sharepoint Overflow an extension of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I found a site today called Sharepoint Overflow (.com).  It looks like StackOverflow, but I can't make out if it is part of the StackOverflow family or not.  I don't want to login and create an account on some rogue site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the home page source:

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

So it looks like it is a SE 1.0 site.

It will eventually be shut down as the migration to SE 2.0 progresses.

Comment: Do SE 1.0 sites not link your accounts?

Comment: @Martin - no, they're completely separate from the original trilogy and new SE 2.0 beta sites.