# Why does the community user have favorites (stars)?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks, community-user

I noticed on the [Network User page](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=favorites) that the Community User has starred a question on the Skeptics site.

So why does the community user have a starred post?  Does the community user own stars from deleted users?  What criteria must be met for the community user to own a star on a post?

**This is not a duplicate of [What can cause the Community user to have favorite questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175992/what-can-cause-the-community-user-to-have-favorite-questions) because that was a site-specific problem for SharePoint; it does not explain the issue on Skeptics.**

Comment: Doesn't answer the question about Skeptics, though.

Comment: Hmm, true. The timeline reveals a tweet twitter.com/#!/StackSkeptic/status/69555636400160768. I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Reopened for the Skeptics case. The dupe does not seem to explain that one.

Comment: If a certain user has a lot of reputation when deleted, their votes might be preserved if stack exchange choses to have their votes preserved. Their votes are considered "owned" by the community user. If a high-rep user has a favorite question and the user is deleted in that special way where the its votes are preserved, their stars normally don't become owned by the community user, but glitches sometimes happen.

Comment: @John I'm aware of the vote ownership transfer when a high rep user's account is deleted.  Do you have an official source that this is the case for the Skeptics example?  From my standpoint, it looks like it's directly related to the StackSkeptic twitter account.

Comment: I don't. That is what I think happened, but I am not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can cause the Community user to have favorite questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175992/what-can-cause-the-community-user-to-have-favorite-questions)

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ This was previously closed as a dupe of that question, but the dupe does not answer the Skeptics case.  See the history here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/291350/timeline.  I do not feel like this is a duplicate.